# Deploy windows services from team city

Tags: msbuild, windows-services, teamcity, msdeploy, windows-server-2012

I want to deploy windows services from our build server running team city to windows server 2012 with minimum server-configuration.

What is one of the best ways to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually use straight powershell or msbuild for this. I try to avoid the flaky msdeploy.
In msbuild you can use the very handy msbuild extension pack thus, so assuming you can copy files to your target destination (Robocopy is handy for that) this will do the rest:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="InstallService" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <UsingTask AssemblyFile="..\packages\MSBuild.Extension.Pack.1.2.0\lib\net40\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll"
TaskName="MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Computer.WindowsService"/>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <MachineName Condition="$(MachineName)==''"></MachineName>
    <ServiceName Condition="$(ServiceName)==''"></ServiceName>
    <ServicePath Condition="$(ServicePath)==''"></ServicePath>
    <User Condition="$(User)==''"></User>
    <Password Condition="$(Password)==''"></Password>
    <SuppressStart Condition="$(SuppressStart)==''"></SuppressStart>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="CheckProperties" BeforeTargets="StopService">
    <Message Text="MachineName: $(MachineName)"/>
    <Message Text="ServiceName: $(ServiceName)"/>
    <Message Text="ServicePath: $(ServicePath)"/>
    <Message Text="User : $(User)"/>
    <Message Text="SuppressStart : $(SuppressStart)"/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="StopService" BeforeTargets="InstallService">

    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Computer.WindowsService
      TaskAction="CheckExists"
      ServiceName="$(ServiceName)"
      MachineName="$(MachineName)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Exists" PropertyName="DoesExist"/>
    </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Computer.WindowsService>

    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Computer.WindowsService
      TaskAction="Stop"
      ServiceName="$(ServiceName)"
      MachineName="$(MachineName)"
      Condition="$(DoesExist)=='True'">
    </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Computer.WindowsService>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="StartService" AfterTargets="InstallService">

    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Computer.WindowsService
    TaskAction="CheckExists"
    ServiceName="$(ServiceName)"
    MachineName="$(MachineName)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Exists" PropertyName="DoesExist"/>

    </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Computer.WindowsService>

    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Computer.WindowsService
      TaskAction="Start"
      ServiceName="$(ServiceName)"
      MachineName="$(MachineName)"
      Condition="$(DoesExist)=='True' And $(SuppressStart)=='False'"
      RetryAttempts="20">
    </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Computer.WindowsService>
    <Message Text="Service $(ServiceName) set not to start" Condition="$(SuppressStart)=='True'" Importance="High" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="InstallService">

    <PropertyGroup>
      <ServiceExeExists Condition="Exists('$(ServicePath)')">True</ServiceExeExists>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Message Text="Installing $(ServicePath) %(ServiceName.Identity)" Importance="high"/>
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Computer.WindowsService
      TaskAction="CheckExists"
      ServiceName="$(ServiceName)"
      MachineName="$(MachineName)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Exists" PropertyName="DoesExist"/>

    </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Computer.WindowsService>

    <Message Text="Installed $(ServiceName) $(ServicePath) for $(User) and $(Password)" Importance="high"/>
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Computer.WindowsService
      TaskAction="Install"
      ServiceName="$(ServiceName)"
      User="$(User)"
      Password="$(Password)"
      ServicePath="$(ServicePath)"
      MachineName="$(MachineName)"
      Condition="!$(DoesExist)"/>

    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Computer.WindowsService
      TaskAction="SetAutomatic"
      ServiceName="$(ServiceName)"
      MachineName="$(MachineName)"
      Condition="!$(DoesExist)"/>
    <Warning Text="%(ServiceName.Identity) service already exists" Condition="$(DoesExist)"/>

  </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: Without having too much experience with msdeploy (used it a couple of times but never really understood how it works "under the hoods"), I must admit that I too feel that it's kind of flaky. That's just opinions however, but I ended up using msbuild with copy-commands and a couple of bat-files. Your solution seems more robust, but needs as you say yourself some kind of fileshare access.

In our case we did! So this solution works & I will mark it as an answer.

Do you know how long "uninstall service" or "stop service" will wait for the service to gracefully stop? Forever?

Comment: Hi Marko glad i could help, from the online docs http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.8.0/index.html it says the that the retryattempts property is defaulted to 60.

Answer (score 1):

We are using the msdeploy package defined like this:

```
<sitemanifest>
  <runCommand path='presync.cmd' waitInterval='30000'/>
  <dirPath path='$winSvc' />
  <runCommand path='postsync.cmd' waitInterval='30000'/>
</sitemanifest>
```

the `presync.cmd`:

```
net stop Svc
installUtil /u /name=Svc $destPath\Svc.exe
```

the `postsync.cmd`:

```
installUtil /name=Svc $destPath\Svc.exe
net start Svc
```

All files are generated by powershell script.

Comment: what if the wait interval is not great enough?